# Linkage problem with extern variable when compiling?

Tags: c, compilation, extern

I'm using MikroC for PIC v7.2, to program a PIC18f67k40.

Within **functii.h**, I have the following variable declaration:

```
extern volatile unsigned char byte_count;
```

Within **main.c**, the following code:

```
#include <functii.h>
// ...
volatile unsigned char byte_count = 0;
// ...

void interrupt () {
    if (RC1IF_bit) {
        uart_rx = Uart1_read();
        uart_string[byte_count] = uart_rx;    
        byte_count++;
    } 
// ...
}
```

Then, within **command.c**, I have the following code:

```
#include <functii.h> 

void how_many_bytes () {
    // ...
    uart1_write(byte_count);
    // ...
}
```

In `main.c`, I process data coming through the UART, using an interrupt. Once the end of transmission character is received, I call `how_many_bytes()`, which sends back the length of the message that was received (plus the data bytes themselves, the code for which I didn't include here, but those are all OK!!).

The problem is that on the `uart1_write()` call, `byte_count` is always 0, instead of having been incremented in the interrupt sequence.

Comment: Do you have any code resetting `byte_count` back to zero? Are you sure that doesn't happen? Also, are you sure that the `interrupt` function is called? And that `RC1IF_bit` is "true"?

Comment: I do, but AFTER `uart1_write(byte_count);`.

Comment: A linkage problem would be warned by the compiler (something like "undefined reference to byte_count"). On the other hand, the linker does not mind if the variable is incremented or not, or your condition is executed or not. As the first comment suggested, it looks like the code is not being executed, due to a wrong interrupts/uart configuration, hardware, etc... Set a break-point inside the condition (`RC1IF_bit`) and see what is going on.

Comment: The "interesting" issue is that reading each value of the `uart_string[]` array gives the correct bytes values. And since the vector is populated by using `byte_count` as the index and it's being incremented at each step, then the interrupt must be running correctly. What seems to happen is that `byte_count` gets reset to 0 somehow, before it's sent back via the UART.

Comment: Also, because I thought that the resetting of `byte_count` may somehow occur before it's being sent back through the UART, I removed that line of code, but the problem is the same. I.e. it comes back through the UART equal to 0.

Comment: Also check for unexpected resets (and the reset reason)

Comment: Tips for how to fix this program: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/329961/6102

Comment: Also related: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/409570/6102

Comment: @AndreiOniga It is difficult to help when we don't see a complete minimal example, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. Even if we cannot run your example without the corresponding hardware the missing code might be necessary to find your problem.

Answer (score -1):

Probably you need some synchronization between the interrupt handler and the main processing.

If you do something like this

```
if(byte_count != 0) {
    uart1_write(byte_count);
    byte_count = 0;
}
```

the interrupt can occur anywhere, for example

1. between `if(byte_count != 0)`and `uart1_write(byte_count);` or
2. during the processing of `uart1_write(byte_count);` which uses a copy of the old value while the value gets changed or
3. between `uart1_write(byte_count);` and `byte_count = 0;`.

With the code above case 1 is no problem but 2 and 3 are. You would lose all characters received after reading `byte_count` for the function call.

Maybe you can disable/enable interrupts at certain points.

A better solution might be to not reset `byte_count` outside of `interrupt()` but instead implement a ring buffer with separate read and write index. The read index would be modified by `how_many_bytes()` (or `uart1_write()`) only and the write index by `interrupt()` only.